# Is it possible in Javascript to close the window that was just opened by window.open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, xss

I'm trying to crash a website a website I'm visiting by blasting it with requests and hopefully overwhelming the server the site is running on. The simple script I made

```
while ( true ) { window.open(window.location.href); }
```

keeps requesting the page I'm on until my browser crashes. So, what I'd like to do is the equivalent of

```
while ( true ) 
{
    window.open(window.location.href);
    CloseTheWindowIJustOpened();
}
```

How do I actually implement that?

Comment: Would answering this encourage this bad behaviour?

Comment: just alter `location.href`onload() to hammer

Comment: @dandavis Can you explain?

Comment: You can also do this with ajax which might be easier. `while(true){ $.get(window.location.href) }`

Comment: `window.onload=location.reload.bind(location)` or, just `location.reload();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing... the `open()` object returns you a [window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) pointing to that new window, and you can manipulate it using it...

example:

```
var win = window.open("", "myNewWindow", "width=200, height=100");
```

then, just invoke that variable and use the `close()` action

```
win.close();
```

*remember* to make your window variable global, so you can invoke it whenever you need:

```
var myWindow = null;

$(function() {
 ...

 myWindow = window.open(...);

});

function closeMyAmazingWindow() {
    myWindow.close();
}

function writeTextOnWindow(txt) {
    myWindow.document.write(txt);
}
```

Comment: As an attack, would this work better if I put some time between requests, using `setTimeout` or something?

Comment: to crash a server you need to perform server requests... `window.open` is a client side ... all you would accomplish is crashing the browser, not the server... and if you want to crash the browser, it's easier to make it do calculations ... calculate the prime numbers in sequence for example... after the 30... it will start to slow a lot :)

Comment: I'm confused ... I thought if  I open a window on a page, then my browser has to make a request  to the server to get the HTML back to my broswer.

Comment: If you do `window.open()` with a URL (like the OP does in the question) it will make a server request. It won't if you do it without a URL, like this answer does.

Comment: I use [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com) on my clients websites, they will throttle the request and the response will have more and more time between requests as it's originated from the same IP in a very short request time (nonhuman)... so, that trick will not work in several websites for example... and if he uses a `setInterval`for more than 1 second, then it's likely to never overcharge the server in question...